# Inherits from DataGridView with custom properties

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I've written my own grid that inherits from DataGridView Class and has a custom properties and columns.

Like this :

```
public class foo : DataGridView {

    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn C1;

    public foo() {
        InitializeClass();
    }

    void InitializeClass() {

      this.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
      C1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
      this.C1.DataPropertyName = "C1";
      this.C1.HeaderText = "Column 1";
      this.C1.Name = "C1";
   }


}
```

The program runs well, but Visual Studio is creating a mess with the code!
In InitializeComponent() Vistual Studio creates again the DataGridViewColumns with its properties :S

Is there any way to avoid this behavior.

Thnks!

**UPDATE : AutoGenerateColumns is set to false**

Comment: Do you have columns defined in the designer?

Answer (score 2):

You could either only create the columns at runtime, I think checking `System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode` works, or hide the `Columns` property with a [`DesignerSerializationVisibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.aspx) attribute.